# Modifying roscpp scripts (msg_gen.py)

Tags: catkin, roscpp, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to make local modifications to msg_gen.py for my packages. I've successfully modified C++ libraries in roscpp by using a copy of roscpp in my workspace, and these changes are picked up by other C++ packages/nodes which depend on the roscpp library.

However, when I modify `roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py`, the changes don't actually take effect — it seems like the `generate_messages()` cmake function in my other packages somehow knows to use the system version (`/opt/ros/indigo/share/roscpp/rosbuild/scripts/msg_gen.py`).

What do I need to do so that `generate_messages()` can use the local, modified version of the message generator?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248333/modifying-roscpp-scripts-(msg_gen.py)/) by [jtbandes](https://answers.ros.org/users/28561/jtbandes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-11-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to modify the code in the [gencpp](https://github.com/ros/gencpp) / [genpy](https://github.com/ros/genpy) packages instead.

The code in `roscpp/rosbuild` is only used when you use `rosbuild` but since you are using `catkin` you need to modify the code in the above packages instead.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2016-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jtbandes](https://answers.ros.org/users/28561/jtbandes/) on 2016-11-18**:
Thanks, that worked! I had to pull `message_generation` into my tree as well, to make it use my version of `gencpp`.